# Projection of dis-joint sets in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two string arrays **( I will not use it anywhere as it is not a good logic,this is for my learning purpose).**

```
string[] names = new[] { "Joss", "Moss", "Kepler" };

string[] emails = new[] { "Moss@gmail", "Kepler@gmail", "Joss@gmail" };
```

How to use LINQ so as to make key value pairs like

```
{"Joss","Joss@gmail"} ,{"Moss","Moss@gmail"} , {"Kepler","Kepler@gmail"}
```

1. email ids are shuffled in string array emails[]
2. consider both string arrays keep unique name and unique email ids
   (their name as email ids).

How to use Join to project the result i want?

```
                          var JoinDemo = from grpname in names
                          join
                          grpmails in emails 
                          on grpname ????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the constraints you defined this should do the job:

```
        var q = from name in names
                join email in emails on name equals email.Remove(email.IndexOf('@'))
                select new
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Email = email
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the [`Zip` operator from .NET 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx). If you can't wait that long, you can use the implementation in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq).

I'm not sure what you mean about the shuffling though... do you really want a random pairing? If so, it's probably easiest to shuffle one array first and then do the zip.

Comment: no not random selection. I shuffled emails[].During selection,the search should select the proper match  ( undisired match {Joss,Moss@gmail.com} desired match { Joss,Joss@gmail.com}.Hope it would clear.Willing to provide info if u still need something.

Comment: No, it's still not particularly clear. What represents a match? Just that the email address starts with the name?

Comment: yes exactly ,I am curious to know how can we perfom it using MoreLinq."Bruno conde" provided the answer.I wish to know how can we apply MoreLinq on that.

Comment: Why did not you add the MoreLinq tag in StackOverFlow ?

Comment: @udana: If you're not matching pair-wise sequentially, you don't need Zip. As for a morelinq tag - tags should be about questions, not answers really.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Zip` operation which is not available in .NET 3.5 BCL out of the box.

If you have two *arrays* (won't work for generic `IEnumerable<T>`) of same length, you can use:

```
var zippedArrays = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length))
                             .Select(i => new { Name = a[i], Email = b[i] })
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: It is working fine.But each name should match to their associate email (here associate represents their name@gmail) for example if the name is Jossi need Joss@gmail {"Joss","Joss@gmail"} in second string array (emails[]) emailids are shuffled.